# Why does Windows Calculator always start minimised?

Tags: windows, focus, calculator

I often start Calculator by pressing the little Calculator button on my MS keyboard - but for some stupid reason it always starts minimized - meaning I have to restore it first before I can use it. Any idea why it would do this?

It appears to start fine if I start it any other way.

**Update:** I've just realized this only happens when Visual Studio 2008 is in focus - which is a lot of the time on my machine. Weird! Still annoying though.

**Update 2:** OK, so it's not just Visual Studio - but Calculator starts without focus in all programs. Some programs it starts under, and some programs it starts over the top, but still not focused - so you have to click on the program itself or on the taskbar.

Comment: what version of windows are you using?

Comment: Man... I so want to say "Because you touch yourself at night." or something... really, that's an odd problem to have. I suggest remapping the calculator button and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Using Vista x64 Business Edition. I know it's odd - I even tried remapping it to start calc.exe manually, but it just does the same thing :|

Comment: Interesting.  Any other programs launch minimized when VS is in focus?  IE, Outlook Express?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with Windows 7 x64.  I fixed it by creating a command file calc.cmd with the following lines:

```
start C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe 
exit
```

Then I assigned the key to run the command file, and calc now starts in the foreground.

Comment: Also a work-around. Let’s try to fix the problem.

Comment: Works for me, Windows 10, Logitech K270

Comment: This is the perfect fix for the Windows 10 calculator that will start in the background *and* with no focus on the numbers line. With this, it starts just like old Windows 7 calculator; on foreground and with proper focus.

Comment: The only solution that works for me on Win 10.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst my keyboard is not a MS keyboard but a Logitech keyboard, I had the same problem. It would either start minimised or out of focus. It was very annoying especially as I use it a lot.

To fix this problem I changed the keyboard button allocation from 'Default Task' (IE: Calculator) to 'Launch Program', then browse to the calculator application (often located in 'C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe') then clicked Apply.

Worked for me...

Comment: I went into the SetPoint settings, added "start " before the "Program:" field under "My Keyboard" -> "Launch Program" and clicked "apply". Then it worked. I changed it back and clicked apply, and it also worked. We'll see if it survives a restart whenever that happens next.

Answer (score 0):

One was this could happen is if that key is mapped to a shortcut with Run set to Minimized.  What kind of MS keyboard?

Comment: It's a standard MS Digital Media keyboard - nothing special. I've looked in the Microsoft Keyboard settings and all the calculator key does is start Calculator. No other options there (such as start minimised, etc).

Comment: I can confirm I have the same keyboard and have never experienced this problem.

Comment: But *how* does it start the calculator? Does it run calc.exe or does it just “run calculator”. What exactly is displayed in the configuration dialog?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com) fix:

```
WinWait, Calculator
WinActivate
```

or compile the following script, drop it into system32 and rename `calc.exe` to `calcX.exe` and name this compiled script `calc.exe`.

```
Run, calcX.exe
WinWait, Calculator
WinActivate
```

Comment: not sure which key AHK uses for calculator in specific, or i'd have a solution to map that key to the above. I know the scan code for the calculator button is E0_21, but I don't know what the AHK authors named it.

Comment: That is just a work-around and doesn’t really address the problem. The OP already has a work-around (restoring the calculator after running it), so it would be better to figure out what the problem is and fix it.

Comment: -1 Replacing system files is dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is not going to be a straightforward answer for this. It is going to require investigation and debugging of your system. Fortunately most of us here love doing exactly that, so let’s start. :)

Try mapping it to something else, say Notepad for example. What happens? Try mapping a different extended button to the Calculator. What happens then? The goal of this step is to see if it is the calculator that is the problem or the specific button.

Comment: That's not only the case of calculator, actually every single program that I start using keyboard shortcuts, like web browser, communicator, music player, and even folders like my documents, my music, my pictures - they're all always start unfocused. A picture of buttons that I'm writing about: http://i.imgur.com/3Jtka.jpg , key assignment: http://i.imgur.com/sTUXl.png

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, fixed this way:

1. open the ms mouse and keyboard settingsin control panel
2. select the calc key
3. disable
4. enable (calc)

Done

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this on multiple systems and either of these worked 100% of the time:

1. The usual suggestion is to pin calc to your taskbar.  You don't have to run it from there, it just being there somehow changes how it's started and will be front and center every time with focus.  So you can then continue to use your keyboard shortcut.  I also noticed that once you pin it, you can remove and it continues to work!  Weird.  I tried to get an answer for this on the calc github but no one could figure out what's going on.  So just pin then unpin.  Done.
2. If you have a keyboard app that lets you assign apps to buttons, DO NOT use whatever default shortcut they have for calc.  If you right-click the start menu item for calc you'll see it's no longer a normal shortcut as of Windows 11.  I believe this to be the problem for many.  If your app allows it specifically select C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe as the app to run for whatever key on your keyboard.

Answer (score -1):

1. Windows start menu;
2. All Programs;
3. Accessories;
4. Calculator;
5. Right-Click Calculator and select Properties.
6. Under the Shortcut tab half way down is the Run attribute; change its property to “Maximized”.

Run your normal shortcut key to open the calculator in maximized state.

Comment: he doesnt want to start it maximized.

Comment: @Keltari: Did you actually read his answer before commenting?

Comment: While the OP doesn't mention OS version, this wont work on Windows 11 moving forward as they no longer use normal shortcuts for system apps.  i.e. there is no "properties" anymore.