# Multiple Copies of Windows Calculator

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-8.1, calculator

Just did a clean install of Win7 x64. I have a Microsoft Ergo Keyboard 4000 and use the calculator key a lot.

Previously, in Windows XP, I could hit it and get multiple copies of calculator to popup. Now it will only show one copy of calculator. I tried adding a shortcut to the calculator app but it has the same limitation. However if I click the calculator icon it will open a new one each time.

How can I fix this so each time I press the calculator key it will open a new copy?

Comment: This is a [known problem](http://superuser.com/questions/70523/windows-7-new-apps-windows-with-no-focus) with no definite known solution, although he stated that installing the keyboard driver after any other interface drivers helped.

Comment: In 2022, with Windows 10, I have the reverse issue. I can't get it to just open the existing calculator instead of spawning new ones :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Finally figured out a solution!**

**UPDATE 2014**

This has been tested on Windows 8 and 8.1 and works.

Using a VBS file will make the calculator instance keep focus.

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe", 0, False
Set oShell = Nothing
```

Just create a text file like calculator.vbs and copy/paste the above code and double click or link the file to your keyboard button.

---

[ORIGINAL ANSWER]

Hopefully this isn't specific to a version of IntelliType. However I'm using IntelliType 8.2 x64 for Windows 7 with my Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000.

Once you have installed IntelliType go to Control Panel -> Keyboard then Key Settings tab.

Find the Calculator button in the Key Name column and click Configure. It will be defaulted to "Starts Calculator" now choose "Start a program, Web page, or file" and locate your copy of calc.exe which should be in your system32 folder. In my case it's "C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe"

Click "Finish" and it's now assigned and working as it did on previous Windows.

Now when you click the calculator button it will open multiple calculators instead of just bringing focus to an existing one.

As part of owning a business I do most of the bookkeeping. And having the ability to rapidly open multiple calculators with the calc button is great!

Answer (score 1):

I have a microsoft keyboard also.  The problem only occurs for me when I install the software for the keyboard.  Uninstall the software and it works fine for multiple calculators again.  Happened under XP and 7.

Comment: For me it would happen regardless if I installed IntelliType. Are you using a Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000? I finally figured out a work around and posted my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't have the perfect answer for you. However, once you have opened the first instance of Calculator in Windows 7 it will appear on the taskbar. If you then hold shift and then click the calculator icon on the taskbar, it will open a new instance. (You could try shift + your calculator key, but I don't think that will work)

Comment: yep I read that as well. I was looking to restore the original functionality of the calc key in XP and even a previous "Beta" copy of Win7. thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 0):

I just pinned the Calculator to the taskbar, then I right clicked and clicked on Calculator and it will open as many instances of the calculator that I want!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Please read carrefully before answering in this forum. The user wants to launch the program via a dedicated keyboard key.

Answer (score 0):

i used shell classic link is http://www.classicshell.net/ and load. search in windows right corner for calc.exe and open file location. add "pin to start menu classic". youll have the old calculator (small) back and can open multiple calculators.